# Bootstrap dropdowns in Durandal 2.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, durandal

I am trying to wire up some bootstrap dropdown navigation in a durandal 2.0 app:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <span>Dropdown</span>
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#/view/a>Option A</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#/view/b">Option B</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Clicking "dropdown" causes Durandal's router to attempt to navigate to the root route (which is "#" or ""). And never opens the menu. Is this correct? Workarounds?

### Update

Tabs suffer the very same problem:

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was actually quite simple. There was no conflict with the routing module. I assumed the bootstrap javascript was included by default on the starter kit, but it is not.

The fix is as simple as adding an additional line to my require dependencies:

```
var system = require('durandal/system'),
    app = require('durandal/app'),
    viewLocator = require('durandal/viewLocator');
require('bootstrap');
```

Note that my require.config is:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../lib/require/text',
        'durandal':'../lib/durandal/js',
        'plugins' : '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
        'transitions' : '../lib/durandal/js/transitions',
        'knockout': '../lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0',
        'bootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
        'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jQuery'
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best option in the long run would be converting those bootstrap widgets into knockout custom bindings (like e.g. https://github.com/billpull/knockout-bootstrap)  or even better into native Durandal widgets.

Check out how Durandal 1.2 messageBox is implemented. This can be used as a rough guideline to convert bootstrap tabs and dropdowns into Durandal widgets. As you can see `href` attributes in the view have been replaced by `data-bind="click: ..."`. In addition you'd have to convert the Bootstrap JavaScript into a Durandal `viewmodel`.

e.g. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

becomes
https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2/blob/gh-pages/App/durandal/messageBox.html

```
<div class="messageBox">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 data-bind="html: title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="message" data-bind="html: message"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" data-bind="foreach: options">
        <button class="btn" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.selectOption($data); }, html: $data, css: { 'btn-primary': $index() == 0, autofocus: $index() == 0 }"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** Here's a minimalistic tab widget implementation. Live version at http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#bootstrap

**view:**

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: { data: settings.items }">
        <li data-bind="css: {active: isActive}">
            <a data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.toggle.bind($parent)"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" data-bind="foreach: { data: settings.items}">
        <div class="tab-pane"  data-bind="html: content, css: {active: isActive}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**viewmodel:**

```
define(['durandal/composition', 'jquery'], function(composition, $) {

    var ctor = function() { };

    ctor.prototype.activate = function(settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    };

    ctor.prototype.detached = function() {
        console.log('bootstrap/widget/viewmodel: detached', arguments, this);
    };

    ctor.prototype.toggle = function(model, event){
        this.deactivateAll();
        model.isActive(true);

    };

    ctor.prototype.deactivateAll = function(){

        $.each(this.settings.items(), function(idx, tab){
            tab.isActive(false);
        });
    };

    return ctor;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. Additionally, knockout custom bindings are best when then widget in question depends on an observable, and it doesn't in my case. Still, this is quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the containing a element to a div or span instead of an anchor tag?

Comment: Yes. This totally removes all styles and it still doesn't fire a dropdown.